# Does Odoo 8/9 have multi-currency ecommerce feature?

Tags: odoo, currency, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-website

Does anyone have any documentation or know if odoo version 8/9 have multi-currency for their ecommerce website? Like a drop down menu for changing currency and language?

Comment: You can use website pricelists/

Comment: i tried the website_custom_pricelist but it only set one price at a time in the backend. on the frontend, is there a way for users to change different price list themeselves?

Comment: Just set it to be selectable (checkbox).

Comment: @mokiSRB i am still a little bit lost. i have been searching around for hours but couldnt set it to be selectable. would you please clarify a little for me please? thanks

Comment: @mokiSRB ok i've found your dropdown but only in odoo 9 and not odoo8. thanks

Answer (score 3):

This answer is in two faces 1. Multi-currency in web/ eCommerce 
2. Multi-Language

### Face 1 : Multi-currency in web/ eCommerce

For v8

For odoo v8 there is no default facility available to use the multi-currency feature.
You can go to the below link, and download app for the v8 your problem will solve
https://shop.emiprotechnologies.com/set-your-custom-pricelist-for-website.html

For V9

**Step 1 Select the currencies**

To select currencies to go to **Accounting->Multi-Currencies->Currencies,** check those currencies applicable to you, i.e. USD, MYR, SGD etc ... and then make sure you select the ACTIVE check box! If not available create it

[image: Select-currencies-odoo]

**Note :** *In Accounting >> Configuration >> Setting >> Feature >> Allow Multi Curriciens feature is must be activated.*

[image: Multi-currencies-Configuration-Accounting-odoo]

**Step 2 Set Price List**

To set the Price list for the eCommerce/ Web, go to sales >> Configuration >> PriceList >> Website Pricelist

[image: Multi-currencies-Configuration-Accounting-odoo]

**Note:** *If you have tick/ checked the check box Selectable than only it will available on web/eCommerce*

### Face 1: Multi-Language

It is same for the all **v8,v9, and V10**

From the footer of the Web-odoo, anyone can manage the Multi-Language. as shown in below Image.

[image: Multi-Language]